# How can I auto-populate field in add item Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, document-library

I'm developing a SharePoint 2010 Foundation Farm Solution.
I've created a Document Library (Attachments) with 3 custom field (A,B,C).

I open a pop-up like image below with this code:

```
function openDialog() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.resizable = 1;
    options.scroll = 1;
    options.url = "http://site/Lists/MyList/Forms/Upload.aspx";
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, function () { });
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

[image: Upload attachment pop-up]

After upload I would pass value parameter (Can I perform this by JavaScript?) and disable modify feature.

[image: Meta-data of attachment]

How can I develop this feature?

P.S.: I know value of A B C yet in openDialog() method.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: do you mean that the value C is not known beforehand? Can you provide some more detail about the value source? It is calculated? how?

Comment: Hi. I know the value of A B C yet in openDialog() method.

Comment: Yes you can perform that by JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

The dialog used for entering metadata is called EditForm. What you can do is, pass the parameter values as a query string to that form.

Then use JavaScript to read the query string values and populate the fields.